# CuryUnitCost on Purchase Order Screen, POLine DAC

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to update the CuryUnitPrice field on Purchase Orders Screen with the custom field value from SOLine DAC when the purchase order is processes from Create Purchase Orders Screen. Any Idea on how to do this?

Right now I am trying to get the POLine based on the OrderNbr field. This field is Autonumbered and has "  value in it. I tried all the possible ways to get the value of created POOrderNbr. But somehow I found it in RowSelectedEvent handler after triggering so many times. It is not a good idea to retrieve values for RowSeletedEventhandler. Is there any way I could get this value for updating the field either form Create Purchase Order screen or Purchase Order Screen. Below is the code I have written in RowSelectedEventHandler

```
            protected virtual void POLine_RowSelected(PXCache cache,       PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del)
            { 
                del.Invoke(cache, e);
                POLine row = e.Row as POLine;
                if (row != null)
                {
                   if (row.OrderNbr != " <NEW>")
                   {            
                     PXResultset<POLine> poLine = PXSelect<POLine, Where<POLine.orderNbr,
                     Equal<Required<POLine.orderNbr>>>>
                     .Select(Base, row.OrderNbr);
                       foreach (POLine p in poLine)
                       {
                        PXResultset<SOLineSplit> SoLineSplit = PXSelect<SOLineSplit, Where<SOLineSplit.pONbr,
                            Equal<Required<POOrder.orderNbr>>, And<SOLineSplit.pOLineNbr, Equal<Required<POLine.lineNbr>>>>>.Select(Base, row.OrderNbr, p.LineNbr);

                            foreach (SOLineSplit so in SoLineSplit)
                            {

                            SOLine soLine = PXSelectJoin<SOLine, InnerJoin<SOLineSplit, On<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLineSplit.orderNbr>>>>,
                                 Where<SOLineSplit.planID, Equal<Required<SOLineSplit.planID>>>>.Select(Base, so.OrderNbr, so.PlanID);
                            SOLineExt soLineExt = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(soLine);
                                if (soLineExt.UsrUnitCost != null)
                                {
                                p.CuryUnitCost = soLineExt.UsrUnitCost;

                                Transactions.Update(p);

                                Base.Actions.PressSave();
                                }
                            }
                       }                      
                    }
                  }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try RowPersisted event on POLine:

```
protected virtual void POLine_RowPersisted(PXCache cache, PXRowPeristedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if ((e.Operation & PXDBOperation.Command) == PXDBOperation.Insert ||
        (e.Operation & PXDBOperation.Command) == PXDBOperation.Update)
    {
    }
}
```

Or POOrder if necessary:

```
protected virtual void POOrder_RowPersisted(PXCache cache, PXRowPeristedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if ((e.Operation & PXDBOperation.Command) == PXDBOperation.Insert ||
        (e.Operation & PXDBOperation.Command) == PXDBOperation.Update)
    {
    }
}
```

I think the issue is that POOrderNbr is available only after the record has been persisted to database.